# Number of chiral centers in penicillin V

Tags: stereochemistry, chirality, drugs

I have often seen that in many drugs chirality plays a role. So I was trying to analyze the structure of Penicillin V.

[image: Penicillin V]

What is number of chiral centers in the structure of penicillin V? Is the nitrogen which is  a part of the four membered ring to be counted here because I have read that the nitrogen atom without pyramidal inversion is treated as chiral. So can the nitrogen at bridgehead position be treated as chiral? Because that makes the stereocenter count 4 while on pubchem website the count is mentioned  to be 3.

Comment: Where did you read that?

Comment: Well, the beta-lactam nitrogen is pyramidal: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/pdf/10.1021/ja00721a032

Comment: For _this_ structure in question, count only the sites where carbon is the [stereogenic centre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereocenter).

Comment: Nitrogen atoms in amides (peptide bond) are usually considered planar.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here Nitrogen has to be considered as a stereocenter. Also, you can assign R and S to it. The rule is that the lone pair has the least priority and then you can assign R and S as you do for other molecules.

Comment: In terms of CIP-rules, I agree.  For the triple substituted nitrogen, however, I assumed [nitrogen inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_inversion) still could occur, thus discounting this site.  Maybe N's simultaneous participation in a five and a four membered ring does not permit the large «umbrella flip» otherwise seen / taught with amines thrice substituted by alkyl chains so ChemSE users with experience in quantum chemistry can provide an estimate for the activation barrier to interconvert the two states into each other to support either perspective about this substrate.

Comment: You cannot assign _R_ and _S_ to the nitrogen; the geometry of the amide nitrogen is closer to trigonal planar (sp2).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot consider the bridge-head nitrogen as it's lone pair is in ***resonance with the adjacent oxygen, thus the nitrogen becomes sp2*** rather than being sp3, which is a necessary condition to consider any atom to be a chiral center.
The same thing applies to the other nitrogen in pencilin.

Comment: Please expand your answer and cite references. Unsupported answer may get deleted.